# having trouble with gan training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am a beginner developer who is just studying deep learning in Korea.

I want to train a 512x512 image to generate a new image.

So, after loading the image as shown below, I made a generator model and a discriminator model.

```
dataset = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    datadir, label_mode=None, image_size=(512, 512), batch_size=32
)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x / 255.0)

discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(512, 512, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="discriminator",
)
discriminator.summary()

latent_dim = 128

generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(128,)),
        layers.Dense(8 * 8 * 128),
        layers.Reshape((8, 8, 128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="generator",
)
generator.summary
```

I am trying to create an image by running the loop as shown below.

```
class GAN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.d_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="d_loss")
        self.g_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="g_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.d_loss_metric, self.g_loss_metric]

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Decode them to fake images
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)

        # Combine them with real images
        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images
        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        # Add random noise to the labels - important trick!
        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images"
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.d_loss_metric.update_state(d_loss)
        self.g_loss_metric.update_state(g_loss)
        return {
            "d_loss": self.d_loss_metric.result(),
            "g_loss": self.g_loss_metric.result(),
        }

class GANMonitor(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, num_img=3, latent_dim=128):
        self.num_img = num_img
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(self.num_img, self.latent_dim))
        generated_images = self.model.generator(random_latent_vectors)
        generated_images *= 255
        generated_images.numpy()
        for i in range(self.num_img):
            img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(generated_images[i])
            img.save("/repo/ghpark/tmp/generated_image/generated_img_%06d_%d.png" % (epoch, i))


epochs = 5000

gan = GAN(discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, latent_dim=latent_dim)
gan.compile(
    d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
)

gan.fit(
    dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[GANMonitor(num_img=1, latent_dim=latent_dim)]
)
```

However, in the process of concating, an error like this occurred, and there seems to be a problem with the input shape.

**ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 64 and 512. Shapes are [64,64,3] and [512,512,3]. for '{{node concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](generator/conv2d_3/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext, concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,64,64,3], [?,512,512,3], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <0>.**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this.

```
generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(128,)),
        layers.Dense(8 * 8 * 128),
        layers.Reshape((8, 8, 128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        # layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=4, strides=4, padding="same"),
        # layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="generator",
)
```

I changed the model of the generator.